# How to normalize Api response to particular structure using Ramda js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Suppose we have some nested and unNormalized data  coming from Api, how i can simplify the response using Ramda so that it can be used in easy way in fron end apps.

Convert this response

```
{
  articles: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Dagon",
      tags: [{ id: 1, name: "old ones" }, { id: 2, name: "short story" }]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Azathoth",
      tags: [{ id: 1, name: "old ones" }, { id: 3, name: "novel" }]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "At the Mountains of Madness",
      tags: [{ id: 4, name: "insanity" }, { id: 3, name: "novel" }]
    }
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
  articles: {
    byId:{
        1: { title: "Dagon", tags: [1, 2] },
        2: { title: "Azathoth", tags: [1, 3] },
        3: { title: "At the Mountains of Madness", tags: [3, 4] }
    },
    allIds:[1,2,3]
  },
  tags: {
        byId:{
        1: "old ones",
        2: "short story",
        3: "novel",
        4: "insanity"
        },
        allIds:[1,2,3,4]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would probably write it like this:

```js
const articles = R.pipe(
  R.prop('articles'),
  R.applySpec({
    allIds: R.pluck('id'),
    byId: R.pipe(
      R.groupBy(R.prop('id')), 
      R.map(
        R.pipe(
          R.head, 
          R.evolve({ tags: R.pluck('id') }), 
          R.dissoc('id'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  }),
);

const tags = R.pipe(
  R.prop('articles'),
  R.pluck('tags'),
  R.flatten,
  R.uniqBy(R.prop('id')),
  R.applySpec({
    allIds: R.pluck('id'),
    byId: R.pipe(
      R.groupBy(R.prop('id')), 
      R.map(R.path([0, 'name'])),
    ),
  }),
);

const normalize = R.applySpec({ tags, articles });

const data = {
  articles: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Dagon",
      tags: [
        { id: 1, name: "old ones" }, 
        { id: 2, name: "short story" },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Azathoth",
      tags: [
        { id: 1, name: "old ones" },
        { id: 3, name: "novel" },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "At the Mountains of Madness",
      tags: [
        { id: 4, name: "insanity" },
        { id: 3, name: "novel" },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

console.log('result', normalize(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: You might want to replace `map(prop('id'))` with `pluck('id')`.

Comment: This does not normalize `tags` in each article.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting because usually have the opposite problem: I have normalized data from a service that I want to de-normalize on the client.  I can see how this can arise, but it's different from my experience.

I would probably write it like this:

```js
const articles = pipe(
  prop('articles'),
  reduce((a, {id, title, tags}) => ({...a, [id]: {title, tags: pluck('id', tags)}}), {})
)

const tags = pipe(
  prop('articles'),
  pluck('tags'),
  flatten,
  reduce((a, {id, name}) => ({...a, [id]: name}), {})
)

const normalize = (resp, as = articles(resp), ts = tags(resp)) => ({
  articles: {byId: as, ids: keys(as)},
  tags: {byId: ts, ids: keys(ts)}
})

const resp = {articles:[{id:1,title:"Dagon",tags:[{id:1,name:"old ones"},{id:2,name:"short story"}]},{id:2,title:"Azathoth",tags:[{id:1,name:"old ones"},{id:3,name:"novel"}]},{id:3,title:"At the Mountains of Madness",tags:[{id:4,name:"insanity"},{id:3,name:"novel"}]}]};

console.log(normalize(resp))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {pipe, prop, reduce, pluck, flatten, keys} = ramda    </script>
```

The `reduce` step in `tags` could be replaced by `map(values), fromPairs`, but that feels like a hack, as it depends on the order of the properties in the tags.

One difference from your requested output is that I keep the tag ids in the original order of the tags for the article.  Thus `article 3` has tags `[4, 3]` instead of your `[3, 4]`.  I think this makes more sense, as it's possible that there is some intrinsic ordering to tags, but obviously if you don't like that, you could simply add a `sort` step.